# Computing a constant based on current time

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to return a constant string value say

"A" if the current time span is falling `between 06:00 – 14:00` and

"B" if the current time falls `between 14:00 – 22:00`. If both the cases are not satisfied, then It should return "C"

Please suggest the best way to achieve this.

Comment: You can't determine "when" a TimeSpan is. A TimeSpan is an interval and has no relation to the current instant of time.

Comment: What would be returned if the value does not belong both ranges?

Comment: Start by saying `int h = DateTime.Now.Hour;`. Then if `h` is greater than or equal than `6` and less than `14`, take `"A"`. And so on.

Comment: Are the boundaries inclusive or exclusive.  In other words, if it is 6:00 exactly, should "A" be returned?  If it is 14:00? should "A" be returned or "B"?  If it is 22:00, should "B" be returned?

Comment: @Dan if 14:00 then A, if 14:01 then B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
static string GetValue(DateTime date)
{
    var time = date.TimeOfDay;
    if (time.TotalHours >= 6 && time.TotalHours < 14)
    {
        return "A";
    }

    if (time.TotalHours >= 14 && time.TotalHours < 22)
    {
        return "B";
    }

    return null;
}
```

This code will return "B" if the time is 14:01.

Comment: Then, your right-most inequalities should be changed from `<=` to `<`.

Answer (score 0):

> The value of the [DateTime.]Hour property is always expressed using a 24-hour
>   clock.
>   [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.hour.aspx)

But well, your date must be of type `DateTime`, not `TimeSpan`.

Comment: did you mean to put a link for the `DateTime` text?

Comment: No. I just added the DateTime word, because this is missing on the MSDN page. It would have been confusing without that. And I think that's the proper quotation technique, isn't it?

Comment: Oh, it's a quote from MSDN. I didn't get that

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [Datetime.Compare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.compare.aspx) to compare two times.

Answer (score -1):

```
if (DateTime.Now.Hour >= 6 && DateTime.Now.Hour <= 14)
    return "A";
else if (DateTime.Now.Hour >= 14 && DateTime.Now.Hour <= 22)
    return "B";
```

Comment: This won't work because "A" would be returned if the time was 14:01.  In that case, "B" should be returned but it's not.

Comment: Don't call the `.Now` getter four times. The "Now" may change while your code runs.